# VB.NET Wrong input string format error only on one control of two on the same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date-formatting

I have 2 textboxes that use type=date parameter that shows date like dd/MM/yyyy

```
<asp:TextBox Type="date" runat="server" ID="txtScadenza" name="txtScadenza" placeholder="Scadenza" required="required" AutoPostBack="true" class="form-control input-md"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Type="date" runat="server" ID="txtScadenzaDip" name="txtScadenzaDip" placeholder="Scadenza" AutoPostBack="false" class="form-control input-md" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Those textboxes receive a date with this code:

```
txtScadenza.Text = Cliente.Scadenza.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
txtScadenzaDip.Text = Utente.dataScadenza.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Both fields, Scadenza and DataScadenza are DateTime fields on a SQL db. The only difference is that DataScadenza is nullable, Scadenza is not.
I'm receiving the error in the title ONLY on txtScadenzaDip, instead txtScadenza is showing the date with the right format... it's driving me insane. When receiving the error I know that the field DataScadenza has this value: 2021-09-17 00:00:00.000
Where is the problem, please?

Comment: Is there a copy paste error in your question? The two textboxes have the same ID and name.

Comment: I don't get a Type property in asp:TextBox. Are you looking for TextMode?

Comment: You say that the UI shows dates in "dd/MM/yyyy" format yet the code uses `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`. What's up with that?

Comment: @Mary yes indeed, I corrected it :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney I honestly don't remember, I'm following a consolidated practice of mine, I just come to understand that those controls want dates in english format even if they display it in local format. Even when I have to save those dates to the db I have to use parseExact function like this Dim scadenza As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtScadenzaDip.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")).Date

Comment: I just pay attention to another part of the error page that says InvalidCastException: Invalid cast of the string "yyyy-MM-dd" to the 'Integer' type... ???

Comment: That last error message is likely related to your second code snippet. Passing a format string as an argument to `ToString` is only supported for certain types, e.g. `Date`. If `Cliente.Scadenza` and/or `Utente.dataScadenza` are type `String` then that code is interpreted as your calling `ToString` to get a `String` and then indexing that `String` to get a `Char`. Obviously the `String` "yyyy-MM-dd" cannot be converted to a numeric index, hence the error. You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project and then mistakes like that will be flagged by the compiler instead of at run time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney please see my own answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that there is much difference between a simple DateTime object and a Nullable DateTime object, here what I needed to do to make it work:

```
Dim dataScadenza As DateTime
If Utente.dataScadenza.HasValue Then
   dataScadenza = Utente.dataScadenza
   txtScadenzaDip.Text = dataScadenza.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
End If
```

EDIT
As jmcilhinney has pointed out, there's another and simpler solution, using the ? operator:

```
txtScadenzaDip.Text = Utente.dataScadenza?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Actually, `txtScadenzaDip.Text = Utente.dataScadenza?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` would have worked in place of all that code. Once execution reaches the null propagation operator, it will return `Nothing` if the preceding expression evaluates to `Nothing`, otherwise it will continue with the result as the basis for the rest of the expression. That would be functionally equivalent to `txtScadenzaDip.Text = If(Utente.dataScadenza.HasValue, Utente.dataScadenza.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), String.Empty)`.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't change the fact that you should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects. That would have alerted you to the fact that there was a problem when you initially wrote the code and would have made it much easier to solve.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ok noted, I didn't know the ? operator, thank you!